# Centering Image with Z-Index in a Resizable Window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

My images were centering perfectly until I decided to place an image behind another and use z-index. I was using relative positioning, but after moving to absolute, it aligns to the left.

How can I center it, even if window is resized?

Heres my code in a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/WJPhz/

### HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script> 
<center>
    <div id="sign" style="z-index:1">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/bql0ikclb/dope.png" alt"">
    </div>
    <div id="numbers" style="z-index:0">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/z3j212sov/image.png" alt"">
    </div>
</center>
```

### CSS

```
#sign {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
}

#numbers {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sign').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
     $('#numbers').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);

     $("#sign").click(function() {
            $('#sign').fadeOut(3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you really still using the `<center>` tag?  Wow.

Comment: No code in your Fiddle :)

Comment: margin: auto; does not work with position: absolute/fixed; as far as i know.

Comment: Oops sorry muneeb! Here you go:http://jsfiddle.net/WJPhz/

Comment: hahaha, center tags and jquery 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one maybe this can help http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/WJPhz/1/

**CSS**

```
left:50%;
margin-left: -120px; /*div width divide by 2*/
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to put your images in another div and center that div:

**html**

```
<div class="center">
    <div id="sign">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/bql0ikclb/dope.png" alt"" />
    </div>
    <div id="numbers">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/z3j212sov/image.png" alt"" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.center {
    position:relative; 
    max-width: 241px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#sign {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}

#numbers {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WJPhz/2/

Comment: I was to slow :D the only thing i would have added is, that if the `margin: auto` does not work in IE, the `doctype` needs to be changed so that it is not in quirks mode (but to be honest i currently don't know up to which version this is a problem)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. While this example works perfectly, @Markipe's answer is much shorter, concise, and makes more sense to use on the small page I'm working on (coming soon page). Again thank you! If I work on a much more complex page, I'll definitely be using your method! :)

Comment: @user1886754 no problems - just to let you know, the [center tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center) has been deprecated since 1998

Comment: @Pete thank you. It's just a habit to try every single thing, when something doesn't work. I figured eff it, what if it somehow does work haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sign {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:calc(50% - 120px);
}

#numbers {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 241px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:calc(50% - 120px);
}
```

This should work.